# Eclipse link: how to filter superclass query by subclass attribute

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a ReadAllQuery for a superclass type that needs to be filtered by an attribute that only exists on one subclass. I'm using single table inheritance, so the attribute is there for all subclass object rows in the DB, but it's only mapped to one subclass domain object in the code. However when I try this query Eclipselink (2.4.0) gives me an exception: Invalid query key [subclassAttribute].

For reference the sql I want to generate would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM superclass
WHERE
    (subclass_discriminator = 'A' AND attribute_a = 1)
    OR
    (subclass_discriminator = 'B' AND attribute_b = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.0 introduced 'TREAT' that will allow you to access and filter using subclass attributes http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_treat.htm